# Код не работает в сети

Tags: javascript, html

При запуске с локальной машины, все идеально. Но при выгрузки на web сервер, работать не хочет. Голову сломал, не могу понять. Может чего не вижу?

UPD: Фотки должны в случайном порядке отображаются при каждой перезагрузке страницы.

UPD2: Не происходит смена изображений. Видна лишь фотография путь к которой прописан в теге img. Консоль ошибок не выдает.

```
window.onload = function () {
demoFoto();
}
// Предварительная загрузка изображений
numimgF=0
imgslideF=new Array() 
imgslideF[0]=new Image() 
imgslideF[1]=new Image() 
imgslideF[2]=new Image() 
imgslideF[3]=new Image()
imgslideF[4]=new Image()

imgslideF[0].src="images/slideFoto/sf1.jpg" 
imgslideF[1].src="images/slideFoto/sf2.jpg" 
imgslideF[2].src="images/slideFoto/sf3.jpg" 
imgslideF[3].src="images/slideFoto/sf4.jpg"
imgslideF[4].src="images/slideFoto/sf5.jpg"

function demoFoto() {
numimgF = Math.floor(Math.random() * (4 - 0 + 1)) + 0;  
document.getElementById('irfoto').src=imgslideF[numimgF].src
}

//////////// body

<div class="rfoto">
    <img align="center" class="border" height="110" id="irfoto" src="images/slideFoto/sf3.jpg" width="240" /></div>
```

Простите за быдлокод, времени нет по человечески писать =)

Comment: Так что именно не работает? На что ругается?

Фотографии не отображаются или demoFoto не вызывается? Опишите проблему подробнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз src у `img` вообще не меняется, значит, `demoFoto()` не видит на что менять. Возможно стоит попробовать перенести определение массива тоже в событие `window.onload` до вызова функции или же даже в саму функцию, что еще и позволит написать код гораздо короче:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
demoFoto();
}
function demoFoto() {
img="images/slideFoto/sf"+Math.round(Math.random()*4)+".jpg";
document.getElementById('irfoto').src=img
}
</script>
```

И проверьте правильной относительных путей к картинкам, вызываемых через скрипт.

Comment: Да, пробовал и в onload перенести, не помогло.
Пути проверил, изображения доступны.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Дело, скорее всего, в доступе к фотографиям на диске. Проверьте существование путей на сервере. Если сервер никсовый - там имена файлов и папок чувствительны к регистру. Проверьте наличие у пользователя, под которым работает веб-сервер, прав на доступ к папкам, где лежат фотки.

Comment: Думал об этом, но то фото что прописано в теге img отображается. Не происходит смены изображения при перезагрузки страницы.

Comment: А src у irfoto меняется?

И зачем создавать набор img-элементов, если их потом не используете??? Для адреса достаточно было бы хранить массив адресов.

Comment: src не меняется.
Набор img-элементов роли не сыграл.

Так и не пойму в чем дело.

Comment: при вашем способе генерации нового индекса картинка и не должна меняться каждый раз при перезагрузке страницы. На каждый индекс выпадает диапазон случайных чисел длиной в 0,2. Как по-моему, довольно много.

Comment: При запуске с локальной машины, скрипт работает.
А вот после выгрузки на web сервер, нет.

Comment: Может ссылку дадите на тот самый web-сервер, где не работает?

Так проще было бы найти причину.

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо за помощь.
К сожалению с помощью native решит проблему не удалось.

Но решение нашлось с помощью пары строк jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

function demoFoto() {
var numimgF = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 1 + 1)) + 1;  
$('#irfoto').attr('src','путь к файлу'+numimgF+'.jpg');
}

demoFoto();

});
</script>

//// body
<div class="rfoto">
<img class="border" id="irfoto" src="путь к файлу/sf3.jpg" align="center" width="240" height="110">
</div>
```

Вот такой вот странный случай.

Скорей всего код не работал из-за наличия ошибки в другом скрипте, который запускается раньше чем этот.